# IIS server, using browser I get 200 response - curl I get 302 response

Tags: iis, curl

When I use a browser (chromium or firefox) when accessing a page I get the expected results - 200 responses and it displays the information I was expecting.

When I use curl, I get a 302 response:

```
$ curl http://........./Home/Healthcheck
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/Views/Shared/Error.aspx aspxerrorpath=/Home/Healthcheck">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chances are the browser is receiving the 302 as well, but then automatically following the link to the moved position. IIRC you can configure curl to do the same using the --location option.